# rabbitmqadmin is not recognized on windows

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqadmin

```
'rabbitmqadmin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried `rabbitmq-service remove` and `rabbitmq-service install`
but not work

I can't find the folder that contains rabbitmqadmin file on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rabbitmqadmin` is an external tool.
That you can download using the management UI see the documentation:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html

The standard tool is:
`rabbitmqct`

but there are other command line tools:

- `rabbitmqctl` for service management and general operator tasks
- `rabbitmq-diagnostics` for diagnostics and health checking
- `rabbitmq-plugins` for plugin management
- `rabbitmq-queues` for maintenance tasks on queues, in particular quorum queues
- `rabbitmq-upgrade` for maintenance tasks related to upgrades

see: https://www.rabbitmq.com/cli.html for details

Comment: Whats is ** the management UI** ?   the service is running i just cant contact it.

Comment: it is a plugin, see https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes i have enabled that but i still cant find it.